# grafico ggplot2 con imagenes

Tags: r

alguien sabe si se puede realizar en ggplot2 un grafico de barras utilizando iconos o figuras como se muestra en el siguiente gráfico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa esto: https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/ggpattern/